# Can I do it that code just one "1-dim array"?

Tags: python, arrays, list, reverse

I have this code;

```
list = ["Python", "is", "good", "program"]
newlist = []
for i in range(1, len(list)+1):
    newlist.append(list[-i])
print newlist
```

and output ;

```
['program', 'good', 'is', 'python']
```

so code's goal is reversing words by words.
But I did this code with new list. Can I do it just one list?
I mean just "list", without "newlist" ..

edit: I forget to say, Built-in functions or any ready code are not acceptable because of my school. please your helping related be my code.

Comment: dublicate? probably you didn't read my question. my question not about reverse. my question is about how can i use one list...... please just read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to swap it in place then. Something like this should do.

```
colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "purple"];
for i in range(len(colors) // 2):
    color = colors[i]
    colors[i] = colors[len(colors) - 1 - i]
    colors[len(colors) - 1 - i] = color
print(colors)
```

Comment: why you divided by two?

Comment: @user9654395 Try running the code *without* dividing by 2 and see what happens.

Comment: @user9654395 Because you start at the front and swap the front from the back, then move in and swap the second one from the from with the second one from the back. Once you reach the middle your done as both halves are swapped at the same time. This makes it a little faster than some of the other proposed solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much. this was helpful for me.

Comment: @user9654395 happy to help

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
ls = ["Python", "is", "good", "program"]

for x in range(len(ls)):
    ls.insert(x, ls.pop().lower())
print(ls)
# ['program', 'good', 'is', 'python']
```

It turns every word to lowercase as it iterates through. As an aside, I would not recommend using the reserved `list` keyword.

Comment: I don't know w.loser. It is probably dict or ready code etc. but ready code are not acceptable. In my code, how can I do that? ıf you don't mind of course.

Comment: You are still creating a new list here, which is not what the question asks for.

Comment: @chrisz I have fixed it to modify the list in place, as you suggested.